# Angular JS page loading error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am new to angular and I tried to create a application to add, update and delete information about the lab test. But when the page is loaded one error occurrs. If anybody knows the reason for this please help me. Thank you.

**Error** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAU6w.png)

**ManageLabTest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab Test Management</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dynatable/0.3.1/jquery.dynatable.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="../app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controller/LabController.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controller/main.route.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-controller="ManageLabTest">
<div id="page">
    <div class="header"><img src="../img/logoPCU%20(2).jpg" height="174" width="721"/>
        <h1 class="text-info">Lab Test Details Management</h1>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="page-header">
        </div>

        <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h3><strong>Lab Test Details</strong></h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Patient ID </label>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="Test.patientID"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Test Code</label>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control"ng-model="Test.testCode" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Test Name</label>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="Test.testName"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class='col-md-3 '>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Type</label>
                                    <select ng-model="Test.type"  class="form-control">
                                        <option>Select Type</option>
                                        <option>Critical</option>
                                        <option>Non-Critical</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Date</label>
                                    <div ng-model="Prescription.date">{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group pull-right" ng-submit="addNew()">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New"/>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="clear" ng-click="clear()" onclick="enableAddButton()">
                                        Clear
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="page-header">
            <h3><strong>Add Lab Test</strong></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="data-table2">

                        <tr>
                            <th> Patient ID </th>
                            <th> Type </th>
                            <th> Test Code </th>
                            <th> Test Name </th>
                            <th> Date</th>
                            <th> Edit </th>
                            <th> Delete</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr ng-repeat="Test in Tests">
                            <td> {{Test.patientID}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.type}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.testCode}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.testName}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.date}} </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="editLab(Test._id)"
                                        onclick="enableUpdateButtons()">Edit <span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteLab(Test._id)">Delete <span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group pull-right">


                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="" onclick="">Save/Send</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="page-header">
            <h3><strong>Lab Test Details</strong></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="data-table">

                        <tr>
                            <th> Patient ID </th>
                            <th> Type </th>
                            <th> Test Code </th>
                            <th> Test Name </th>
                            <th> Date</th>
                            <th> Edit </th>
                            <th> Delete</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr ng-repeat="Test in Tests">
                            <td> {{Test.patientID}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.type}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.testCode}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.testName}} </td>
                            <td> {{Test.date}} </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="editLab(Test._id)"
                                        onclick="enableUpdateButtons()">Edit <span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteLab(Test._id)">Delete <span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group pull-right">


                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="" onclick="">Save changers</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**LabController.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('ManageLabTest', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    getLab();
    function getLab() {
        $http.get('/').then(response => {
            $scope.labs = labs;
            $scope.lab = null;
        });
    };

    $scope.clear=function(){
        $scope.lab=null;
    };

    $scope.addLab = () => {
        $http.post('/',$scope.lab).then(function(response){

            getLab();

        });
    };

    $scope.update = () =>{
        $http.put('/'+$scope.lab._id,$scope.lab).then(function(response){

            getLab();
            clear();
        });
    };

    $scope.edit = () =>{
        $http.get('/'+id).then(function(response){
            $scope.lab = response.data;

        });
    };

    $scope.remove = () =>{
        $http.delete('/'+id).then(function(response){

            getLab();

        });
    };

    $scope.Test = [];

    $scope.addNew = function (Test) {
        $scope.Test.push({

            'patientID':"",
            'testCode':"",
            'testName':"",
            'date':""
        });
    };
    $scope.date = new Date();

}]);
```

**Lab.model.js**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LabTestSchema = new Schema({
    patientID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    testCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    testName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    type:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var LabTest = mongoose.model('LabTest', LabTestSchema);

module.exports = LabTest;
```

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
```

**server.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

require('./Interface/DataModel/prescription.model.js');
require('./Interface/DataModel/Lab.model.js');

const PresRouter = require('./Interface/Routers/Prescription.route.js');
const LabRouter = require('./Interface/Routers/Lab.route.js')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/PCU', err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/Interface'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Interface/Pres&Labs/ManageLabTest.html');
});

app.use('/',PresRouter);
app.use('/',LabRouter);

app.listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('app listening on port 3000');
});
```

**Lab.route.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('debug', false);

const router = express.Router();
const LabModel = require('../DataModel/Lab.model.js');

router.get('/',function (req,res) {
    LabModel.find().then(labs => {
        res.json(labs);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

router.post('/',function (req,res) {
    const lab = new LabModel(req.body);
    labs.save().then(labs => {
        res.json(labs);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

router.get('/:id',function (req,res) {
    LabModel.findById(req.params.id).then(data=>{
        res.json(data || {});
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

router.put('/:id',function (req,res) {
    const data = req.body;
    delete data._id;
    const Id = req.params.id;
    LabModel.findByIdAndUpdate(Id,{$set:data}).then(db=>{
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

router.delete('/:id',function (req,res) {
    LabModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(data=>{
        res.sendStatus(200,'success');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**main.route.js**

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider'],function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/ManagePrescription',{
            templateUrl : 'ManagePrescription.html',
            controller : 'ManagePrescription'
        })
        .when('/ManageLabTest',{
            templateUrl : 'ManageLabTest.html',
            controller : 'ManageLabTest'
        })
        .when('SearchPrescription',{
            templateUrl : 'SearchPrescription.html',
            controller : 'ManagePrescription'
        })
        .when('SearchLabTest',{
            templateUrl : 'SearchLabTest.html',
            controller : 'ManageLabTest'
        });
});
```

Comment: can you please add the contents of `app.module.js`

Comment: angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

Comment: you have referenced angular twice, once via the minified version and once via the unminified version, you can only load the angular library once. Remove either the minified version or the unminified version

Comment: although I have removed unminified Version it gives the same error message.

Comment: In "main.route.js", you are defining your function out of Array may be that is a problem try like this  
                                    
   angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider){}]);

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in **main.route.js**
you are defining your function out of Array..

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider'],function ($routeProvider) { 
    //YOUR LOGIC
});
```

The code should look like as below

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) { 
    //YOUR LOGIC
}]);
```